# Trouble passing different datatypes in class template

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with my class template program for a college data structures course. I am writing a basic program that creates a class template, 4 class objects ( 2 ints & 2 doubles), sets their width length thickness and then calculates the volume it would take to pave a road. The first 2 objects are doubles and work just fine, however, when I pass through the int objects, the compiler warns me it is trying to convert the double to an int and may result in data loss. I then get a return volume value of 0, which is not correct.

```
template <class Datatype>
Datatype Road<Datatype>::asphalt(Datatype thickness)
{
  //set inches to feet and calculate volume
  thickness /= 12.0;
  thickness *= length;
  thickness *= width;

  return thickness;
}
```

That is my function. It is the third time it is being called, after two double road objects. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: The warning's pretty self-explanatory, is it not? You're performing integer arithmetic. You deliberately did that by specifying you wanted to work with integer types. If you in fact don't, simply don't.

Comment: You could try using template specialization for the integers

Comment: You could do what @MichaelAlbers says, but you shouldn't. In fact, I don't see the use of templates at all in this example. Functions like these should just accept a `double` and let the compiler handle implicit conversions. What does a `Road<int>` even mean?

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear. These are my objects:

Road<double> road;
Road<double> road2;
Road<int> road3;
Road<int> road4; 

Road 1 and 2 perform as expected. Setting the function return type to double, using a double object, and passing a double variable called thickness.

However, when the program begins to execute road3, it sets the length and width appropriately, but when it gets to the asphalt function, the math operations returns 0. Why is this? I can provide more code if needed

Comment: @BossFoxx Your question was perfectly clear. The answer is integer arithmetic, as @Lightness hinted at. What I am saying is that this isn't a good use-case for templates. You should let the `asphalt` member take a `double` rather than a `DataType`. And it's probably even so that you shouldn't have `Road` be a template at all.

Comment: The question was perfectly clear, and repeating it doesn't change my answer.

Comment: Ahh I see the error of ways. @LightnessRacesinOrbit apologies for my momentary blindness. Did not understand your response until I changed the parameter for asphalt to be a double instead of a data type, per JorenHeit's suggestion, and noticed that my values were less than 1, previously truncating my value to a 0. Appreciate the help.